# Having trouble deleting a cookie with multiple values

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm having some trouble deleting a cookie containing multiple values - the values are split by a (*).

If the cookie contains only one (1) value I can easily delete it, but as soon it has more than one I've to hit the button two times in order to delete the cookie... - do I need to define the cookie value in the script, and if so, how...?

```
$('a.home').click(function (e) {
  $.cookie('breadcrumbs', null, {path:'/'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js). If so, it works fine here in Fx 9.0.1

```
$.cookie('foo', 'bar*baz');
//"foo=bar*baz"

$.cookie('foo');
//"bar*baz"

$.cookie('foo', null);
//"foo=null; expires=Tue, 31 Jan 2012 11:34:16 GMT"

$.cookie('foo');
//null (actual null, not string "null")
```

Comment: Yes I did - however I did'nt use it on every pages - hence I had to hit the button two times... - works the way I whant it now... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The plugin makes internal use of [encode/decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), which affects the * character.

Looking at the $.cookie api you should be able to do

```
 $.cookie('breadcrumbs', null, {path:'/', raw: true});
```

to prevent decodeURIComponent being run on your value (you'll probably have to sepecify raw: true when creating the cookie too)

Comment: I completely missread the encodeURI docs, and * is in fact one of characters unaffected by it, so this answer's unlikely to be any help

Comment: Also, on deletion, no value is set. A null value is given with a negative expiration. Thus even if the `*` were to be encoded, it should have effect on deletion.